# How do I obtain the output of an .exe file in the same folder

Tags: c#

I have a project named **wfip** in c# vs2010, in that project I am running a wx.exe file in on button click (i.e whenever the button is pressed wx.exe file runs). Everything works fine and output is obtained in the **debug folder** of the project file where my input is also there.

When I run the project wfip.exe instead of getting my output in **debug folder** I need to obtain the output of wx.exe file in **new folder** which consist of only wx.exe and input of that file.

Comment: without the code showing what you do, no one can help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studios Express - change debug output directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565397/visual-studios-express-change-debug-output-directory)

Comment: when i run wfip.exe project file by changed output directory it is not showing any output,unless i copy the  input files and store it in the project wfip.exe file.

Comment: but i need to optain  my output in folder where wx.exe file and its input is stored.

Comment: private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = @"C:\output\run\wx.exe";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
            process.Start();

        }   i need to obtain my o/p in the folder named run ,which consist of input and wx.exe files